# Teste de accuracy de um modelo ARIMA

Tags: r

Estou criando uma função para rodar modelos ARIMA. Após armazenar os resultados da função em um objeto para fazer o teste de accuracy, retorna o seguinte erro:

> Warning message:
>
> In trainingaccuracy(f, test, d, D) : test elements must be within sample

Entretanto, quando é o modelo feito via a função original arima, o teste de accuracy roda normalmente.

Como no código asseguir:

```
SARIMA <- function(x,p,d,q,P,D,Q) {

  m <- arima(x,order=c(0,1,1), seasonal = list(order = c(0, 1, 1), 
    period = 12, method="CSS"))

  m
}

teste <- arima.sim(n=10000, list(ar=c(0.8), ma=c(-0.3)))

f <- SARIMA(teste,p,d,q,P,D,Q)
f
accuracy(f)

m <- arima(teste,order=c(0,1,1), seasonal = list(order = c(0, 1, 1), 
  period = 12, method="CSS"))
accuracy(m)
```

Os dois objetos (`f` e `m`) são da class "arima" e o mesmo mode "list".

Pq quando uso a função SARIMA não roda accuracy?

Comment: Qual é o pacote da função `accuracy`?

Comment: É do pacote forecast.

Answer (score 3):

Embora a tua função `SARIMA` coloque na tela os resultados da série temporal ajustada, o `R` não entende que `m` é, de fato, o resultado final da função. Faça a seguinte alteração e tudo vai funcionar:

```
library(forecast)

SARIMA <- function(x,p,d,q,P,D,Q) {

  m <- arima(x,order=c(0,1,1), seasonal = list(order = c(0, 1, 1), 
    period = 12, method="CSS"))

  return(m) # mude aqui, adicionando a funcao return
}

teste <- arima.sim(n=10000, list(ar=c(0.8), ma=c(-0.3)))

f <- SARIMA(teste,p,d,q,P,D,Q)
m <- arima(teste,order=c(0,1,1), seasonal = list(order = c(0, 1, 1), 
  period = 12, method="CSS"))

accuracy(f)
                       ME     RMSE       MAE      MPE     MAPE      MASE
Training set -0.001113768 1.050208 0.8411787 120.3188 585.0239 0.9316498
                   ACF1
Training set 0.04742673


accuracy(m)
                       ME     RMSE       MAE      MPE     MAPE      MASE
Training set -0.001113768 1.050208 0.8411787 57.34868 431.3339 0.9183245
                   ACF1
Training set 0.04742673
```

Comment: Testei a alteração, mas não deu certo. Obtive o mesmo resultado. Para contornar isso retirei a variável x da função e salvei o objeto teste em x.